# fstab: mounting network drive no longer works after swaping router

Tags: networking, mount, fstab

Because of a problem with a device in our network we had to swap the router from a FritzBox 7390 to a 7590.

Now my fstab mount on my RaspberryPi 3 no longer works:

```
//192.168.1.1/Folder/Folder/Folder /media/Folder cifs username=username,password=password,vers=3.0 0 0
```

dmesg tells me this:

```
[   14.130713] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[   14.130729] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
```

When running `sudo mount -a` it works again but I need it to do that on startup.
Also manual mount works.

Comment: ofc the ` is not part of the second dmesg line I shared. Just a mistake from my side.

Comment: Why don't you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1123559/edit) and correct the typo then?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that

Comment: Is the new router also at 192.168.1.1?